# Why does the DEBUGLOG syntax have 3 dots (...)?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, debugging

I have seen `DEBUGLOG(x,...)` syntax.  It supports `DEBUGLOG(x,...)` or `DEBUGLOG(x...)`.
If we alter dots like `DEBUGLOG(x,..)`, it gives an error. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "variadic" macro, meaning it takes multiple arguments. It's the macro equivalent of a C variadic function like `printf`. The `...` means "and any other arguments beyond here are OK too".

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

> When the macro is invoked, all the
>   tokens in its argument list after the
>   last named argument (this macro has
>   none), including any commas, become
>   the variable argument. This sequence
>   of tokens replaces the identifier
>   **VA_ARGS** in the macro body wherever it appears.

(I'm not certain why "x..." works without a comma. That's not a form you'd usually see.)